# using long (int64) as a hashCode and still use IEqualityComparer for concurrent Dictionary

Tags: c#, hash, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer, concurrentdictionary

I have a problem using a self made IEqualityComparer and GetHashCode in a concurrent dictionary.

The class below (simplified with used two properties) works perfect when I implement it like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<TwoUintsKeyInfo,Int64> hashCodePlusIandJDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<TwoUintsKeyInfo, Int64>();
```

.

```
public class TwoUintsKeyInfo
{
    public uint IdOne { get; set; }
    public uint IdTwo { get; set; }

    #region Implemetation of the IEqualityComparer

    public class EqualityComparerTwoUintsKeyInfo : IEqualityComparer<TwoUintsKeyInfo>
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties;
        bool propertyArraySet=false;

        public int GetHashCode(TwoUintsKeyInfo obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                if(!propertyArraySet)
                {
                    properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
                    propertyArraySet = true;
                }

                decimal hash = 17;
                int counter=0;
                foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in properties)
                {
                    counter++;
                    var value = p.GetValue(obj);
                    decimal unique = (decimal)Math.Pow(Math.E, counter);
                    hash = hash + (value == null ? unique : value.GetHashCode() * unique);
                }
                return 2147483647M * .001M > hash ? (int)(hash * 1000) : (int)hash;
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(TwoUintsKeyInfo x, TwoUintsKeyInfo y)
        {
            return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
        }
    }

    #endregion Implemetation of the IEqualityComparer
}
```

Now I made almost the same class, but instead of the normal IEqualityComparer interface, I made a little change, so I could generate long / int64 hascodes (because when the class hold more and more properties, we encountered multiple values with the same hashcode)

So I wanted to reduce the changes of getting the same hascode. Therefore I wanted to use bigger numbers and if possible multiple by 10000 to get some of the decimals in on the action as well.

therefore I created this interface:

```
public interface IEqualityComparerInt64<in T>
{
    bool Equals(T x, T y);
    Int64 GetHashCode(T obj);
}
```

and altered the property class so it looks like this:

```
public class TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64
{
    public uint IdOne { get; set; }
    public uint IdTwo { get; set; }

    #region Implemetation of the IEqualityComparer

    public class EqualityComparerTwoUintsKeyInfoInt64 : IEqualityComparerInt64<TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64>
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties;
        bool propertyArraySet=false;
        decimal _upperThreshold,_lowerThreshold;

        public EqualityComparerTwoUintsKeyInfoInt64()
        {
            _upperThreshold = long.MaxValue * .0001M;
            _lowerThreshold = -long.MaxValue * .0001M;
        }

        public long GetHashCode(TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64 obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                if(!propertyArraySet)
                {
                    properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
                    propertyArraySet = true;
                }

                decimal hash = 17;
                int counter=0;
                foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in properties)
                {
                    counter++;
                    var value = p.GetValue(obj);
                    decimal unique = (decimal)Math.Pow(Math.E, counter);
                    hash = hash + (value == null ? unique : value.GetHashCode() * unique);
                }
                return _upperThreshold > hash && _lowerThreshold < hash ? (long)(hash * 10000) : (long)hash;
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64 x, TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64 y)
        {
            return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
        }
    }

    #endregion Implemetation of the IEqualityComparer
}
```

GetHashCode worked fine. So far no problem.

But...when I try to add a IEqualityComparer to the concurrentdictionary like this:

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64,Int64> hashCodePlusIandJDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64, Int64>(new TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64.EqualityComparerOneUintAndTwoStringKeyInfo());
```

I get this error:

> Error 3   Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'HasCodeTestForUniqueResult.TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64.EqualityComparerOneUintAndTwoStringKeyInfo'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'   D:\Users\mldz\Documents\visual
>   studio
>   2012\HashCodeTestForUniqueResult\HashCodeTestForUniqueResult\Form1.cs 109 140 HashCodeTestForUniqueResult

I understand that there's a conflict between the int type of the default System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer and my long / int64  result from my own GetHashCode generator. But is there any way to solve this and be able to use long HashCodes?

Kind regards,

Matthijs

P.S. the code above is just to test it and replicate the problem.

Comment: Why create your own data type for a long? (in reference to TwoUintsKeyInfoInt64)

Comment: What do you mean? I want to make the GetHashCode more precise (read: less change of having the same hashcode for different values)

Comment: As a side note, this is not good: `public bool Equals(TwoUintsKeyInfo x, TwoUintsKeyInfo y) { return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y); }`. As you yourself point out, identical hash codes does not necessarily mean that the two objects are the same. Equal is only supposed to return `true` if the two objects are truly identical.

Comment: yep, it's a fix, just to implement the Iequalitycomparer.

Comment: Why are you using reflection here? Why not simply access the two properties directly? In regards to "more precise", do you know that this will be a problem? Do you have an idea of the value distribution and how this impacts the hash code values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you cannot use long hash codes, so the answer to the question is no.

But you can have unique combinations instead of unique values; the solution is to implement a partitioning system, meaning have a dictionary of dictionaries, like:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    Dictionary<uint, Dictionary<uint, Int64>> PartDict;

    Int64 ReadValue(uint id1, uint id2)
    {
        return (PartDict[id1])[id2];
    }

    void AddValue(uint id1, uint id2, Int64 value)
    {
        Dictionary<uint, Int64> container;
        if (!PartDict.TryGetValue(id1, out container))
        {
            container = new Dictionary<uint, Int64>();
            PartDict.Add(id1, container);
        }
        container.Add(id2, value);
    }
}
```

This way you will have a list of hash codes and each hash code will have again a list of hash codes, the combination being unique. Any reading and writing will be done in 2 steps though (to consider in case you want unique hash for performance).

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, I actually implemented a similar solution to get it working. And that seems to be be ok. So, although I already had something like this; check for answer ;-) And thanks for your reply